# How to modify a primary key with Restangular?

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs, crud, restangular

I've got a very simple object, called "tag" that has only a string primary key. When I go to edit it...

```
var tag = Restangular.one('tags', 'cat')
  .get(function() { // fetches { id: 'cat' } from server

    // edit the tag
    tag.id = 'dog';

    // save changes
    tag.post().then(beHappy, beSad);
});
```

The request that gets sent off is a call to:

```
POST /tags/cat/dog
```

with the correct data:

```
{ id: 'dog' }
```

I have no doubt that everything work fine if I wasn't trying to modify my primary key, but my server-side REST API isn't expecting the `/oldId/newId` format, and so I get a 404. Is this a bug in [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular), or does my REST API need repairing?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I've been doing CRUD wrong, doing POST for updates and PUT for creates, which is exactly backwards.

Changing it to `tag.put()` fixed it.